# How to properly select an area inside a numpy ndarray

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

How to properly select a specific area inside a NumPy ndarray. For example, in the sample code below I want to select the 2x3 matrix that corresponds to the intersections of columns and rows of matrix M stored in a and b respectively,

```
M = np.random.rand(4,5)
print(M)
a = [0, 2]
b = [0, 2, 3]
Selection = M[a,b]
```

but I am getting:

> IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast
> together with shapes (2,) (3,)

when I want from matrix M:

```
[[0.36899449 0.02531732 0.04966994 0.66058884 0.26193009]
 [0.92893864 0.10193024 0.74850916 0.72822403 0.09112129]
 [0.28863096 0.45470087 0.01032583 0.30931807 0.42765045]
 [0.59819051 0.94057773 0.95352287 0.81818564 0.24220261]]
```

To get:

```
[[0.36899449 0.04966994]
 [0.28863096 0.01032583]
 [0.59819051 0.95352287]]
```

Comment: did you try `M[b,a] `?

Comment: Hi, yes same index error with `M[b,a]`

Comment: Try `M[b][:,a]`

Comment: or try to cast a  and b to numpy arrays

Comment: `M[b][:,a]` works! Thanks